# Int, float - classes?

Tags: python

Little question: are `int`, `float`, `bool`, `list`, `str`, etc. actual classes in python? For example, if we write `x = 5` we create an instance of a class `int` and assign this instance to a variable `x`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct (except that small integers are *interned* in CPython, so `x = 5` would assign an existing `int` instance to the identifier `x`).

Comment: Please take a look in the Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types